# Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, wsl-2, kali-linux

I am developing an app that needs to connect to a BLE device, but i cannot find them to establish a connection and read the bluetooth device(yes, it's on) and i can connect it to another app only from this app . So, i try to sniff the bluetooth connection with bettercap in my kali linux running in WSL2, but when i try "ble.recon on" i get:

```
bettercap v2.28 (built for linux amd64 with go1.14.4) [type 'help' for a list of commands] 
eth0: You don't have permission to capture on that device (socket: Operation not permitted)
```

And, if i try: "hciconfig" i get this issue

```
Can't open HCI socket.: Address family not supported by protocol
```

I think that i need to enable my hci socket or something. I need help.
I'm open to other ideas to establish a connection with tis device

Device: M1001 mopeka

App(working): gascheck

Answer (score 1):

WSL2 isn’t allowed access to the network or bluetooth card directly. It is give an internal bridge IP address. From the outside, windows is making the network connections not kali. So, if you need to use this, maybe you can try dual boot.